# One Drive based MS Access Manipulation via PHP / HTML Website

Tags: onedrive

I'm building a website to keep track of devices within my company. I was planning to keep everything "On The Cloud". I would have all the details on MS Access and store it on One Drive. I wanted to take the data from the OneDrive file, display it on the website and have the ability to edit it and save it.

Only thing is, I don't know how. Any suggestions?

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the free tier of Azure App Service? Assuming you can fit your app and data into a 1 GB of space, you can get up to 10 apps for free at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/

It even supports PHP, and you could stuff the Access DB into the data directory side by side on the same disk... Alternatively, you could scale into SQLite, or even a low end SQL Server DB side by side with the web app...